# Unable to attatch a csv file to mail in objective c

Tags: ios, email, csv

I'm using the following code to attach a csv file that is generated to mail composer.

```
NSString *recipient = @"tejanvm92@gmail.com";
NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipient, nil];

MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setSubject:@"CSV Export"];
[mailViewController setToRecipients:recipients];
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
mailViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"yourFileName.csv"];

[mailViewController addAttachmentData:myData
                             mimeType:@"text/csv"
                             fileName:@"yourFileName"];

[self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
```

When the code runs.....the csv file is not attached to the mail properly.

But When I got the mail, it is empty. Could you please help me in finding the issue?

Comment: yes, I checked  nsdata . It is null.  I think it is because I haven't included the document directory and the path. I wrote the full path and now the nsdata is not null.

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"yourFileName.csv"]// its wrong way.
```

Please write full path of csv file
Like if your csv file in Documents directory.
then

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *csvFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/yourFileName.csv"];
```

after that change in your code

```
 [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:csvFilePath];
```